# How do I stop Android Studio from setting compileSdkVersion to 33 by default on new project creation

Tags: android-studio, gradle, sdk

Every time I create a new module, `compileSdk` is set to 33 by default, in `build.gradle (:module)`. When I try to build that new project, IDE shows an error saying there are libraries I use that require `compileSdk` to be 34 or higher. **That, unfortunately, means that I have to manually set `compileSdk` to the value of 34 every time I start a new project or module.**

I've found that that library is:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0'
```

Or, another approach that I can take (instead of setting `compileSdk` to 34 manually every time I create a new module) is downgrading this library's version from 10 to 9:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
```

And it's working as well.

But what is frustrating me is that they've decided to set me a higher version of the library by default but they don't do it with `compileSdk`. And also none of this would happen 2 days ago (and earlier) when I would create a module (perhaps there has been a silent update). And now I have to change it manually every time.

And I'm wondering why no one is having the same problem I am. I use Linux and I downloaded Android Studio from the Jetbrain's official site: `Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same issue. Found that this was happening when moving from compileSDK 32 to 33. And They say to live with it. Maybe till the next update.

Comment: Вы были правы. С новым патчем теперь при каждом создании нового проекта/модуля значение `compileSdk` автоматически приравнивается к 34.